# How not to skip a page with begin{figure}

Tags: floats

I have this code.

```
\section{Anhang}

\begin{figure}

    \includegraphics{anderegraphen5,6-1.png}

\end{figure}
```

Right now I skip the page after "Anhang" can someone please tell me how I keep the graphic on the same page?

I have already read [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/150162#150162)
, but perhaps i missed the solution in this link.

Perhaps you can give me a direct hint.

Comment: Could you please turn this code snippet into a complete, minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`)? Otherwise, this question can't be reasonably answered (other than with a link to an explanation of how floats work).

Comment: You are missing position indicators: \begin{figure}[ht] for example which tells tex to try to place the figure here or at the top of the page if here is not possible. You can make any combination with `htbp` (here, top, bottom, page with floats) - the list is prioritized.

Comment: @remus I'm not sure what you mean by "the list is prioritized", `[htbp]` is the same thing as `[pbth]`

Comment: As you haven't got a caption you can simply remove the `figure` environment, the only purpose of which is to tell LaTeX it can move the image.